# How to store a JSON into local storage

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to store a JSON into local storage. I am making an ajax call and fetch the JSON which is return by a function in PHP.

Here is my returned JSON:

```
[{
    "Post_id":"4",
    "Post_title":"This is testig",
    "Post_body":"<p>Ki<\/p>",
    "Post_thumnail":"",
    "Post_category":"Sports",
    "Post_Share":"Public",
    "Post_status":"",
    "Post_author":"ajaynegi",
    "Post_time":"2017-06-19 22:26:17",
    "Description":"Hello my name is jitendee"
}]
```

Now I want to store this JSON into local storage and later fetch it.

Regards,
Jitender

Comment: Are you referring to HTML5 local storage (in the browser)?

Comment: yes want to use HTML 5 local storage

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(json));` to store it in the `localStorage` and use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));` to get it later.

To get more insights take a look

- [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)
- [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: Great, Thankyou its work for me. But need one more help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.stringify(jsonobj)` to convert it to string, due to you only can store string values in localStorage.
  When you fetch data back, use `JSON.parse(data)` to get back the object

Comment: could you please provide an example with the above JSON I provided, it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example based on the provided JSON of your question

```
var json = [{"Post_id":"4","Post_title":"This is testig","Post_body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut finibus ipsum. Morbi posuere lacus sit amet libero semper sodales. Aliquam pharetra, magna ac mattis tempus, justo dui volutpat metus, eget pulvinar felis nulla at nulla. Quisque in imperdiet nunc. Cras non mauris turpis. Duis gravida pellentesque purus vitae facilisis. Vestibulum vel ligula consectetur, pretium massa rhoncus, tempor arcu. Aliquam tempor, risus ut commodo fermentum, ligula eros rhoncus quam, a tristique sapien risus in nibh. Duis condimentum enim sit amet sem placerat accumsan. Vestibulum luctus sodales rutrum. Donec viverra sodales odio id consequat. Nulla sodales pretium velit, a sagittis ex rhoncus malesuada.","Post_thumnail":"","Post_category":"Sports","Post_Share":"Public","Post_status":"","Post_author":"ajaynegi","Post_time":"2017-06-19 22:26:17","Description":"Hello my name is jitendee"}];

localStorage.setItem("myJSON",JSON.stringify(json));

var myJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myJSON"))[0];

console.log(myJSON.Post_id);
console.log(myJSON.Post_title);
console.log(myJSON.Post_body);
console.log(myJSON.Post_time);
```

You can check the example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/468o9nwa/)

Comment: Awesome Thank you Peter so much :-)

Comment: @JitenderSingh thanks, just keep in mind that `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` have a limit on how many bytes you can store. Check the storage limit per browser if you want your apps not to have a problem on different browsers. Clear or remove `localStorage` items if you don't need them on other pages of your application or website.

Comment: how can I remove them once the user close the window. ?

Comment: something like this `window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  localStorage.removeItem("myJSON");
}`